# Canon Duplexer prints on opposite sides

Tags: macos, printing, canon

I have a problem I cannot fix. The CANON i-Sensys MF4660PL printer I have is able to print double-sided, but it does not do it correctly. I have downloaded the latest printer driver from Canon (for El Capitan), and tried different drivers and settings in the printer, but after one-and-a-half hour I am inclined to give up.

THe problem is that it prints on opposite sides; so yes, it does print on both sides, but you have to turn around the page to continue reading. I have also changed the Long-edge vs Short-edge binding setting in the printing settings, and the 'Auto-Rotate' setting, to no avail.

Google does not seem to help me either... Anyone?

Comment: Would please tell me what application you are using and what type of files you are printing? (I'm guessing Pages.app...)

Comment: sorry to be incomplete. I have tried printing PDF files using Google Chrome (the built-in PDF reader and print utility) as well as PDF print through Preview. I have also tried printing a regular HTML web page (in Chrome).